# Horizontal slider for php generated gallery of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a horizontal slider for my clients customly added gallery. Elements are show as no-wrap, multi-window-width block that is meant to change it `margin-left` once slider arrows left or right are clicked.

The value it should increase/decrease margin-left by have to be a `variable`, because it should be working regardless of current responsive css document loaded.

I've created a script that would get `photo-container` div width, save it as variable and later on use it as right-hand side argument in `animate()` function, still it wouldn't work the way i would like it to. In fact, it would actually not work at all, or show an invalid tween error in console.

**My script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           var imageWidthToSlice = $(".gallery-element-wrapper").css("width");
            imageWidth = imageWidthToSlice.slice(0, -2);
            defaultMargin = $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").css("margin-left").slice(0, -2);
            numberOfElements = $(".gallery-element-wrapper").length;
            totalWidth = imageWidth * numberOfElements;

            $(".gallery-arrow").click(function() {
               if ( $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").css("margin-left").slice(0, -2) != defaultMargin ) {
                   $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").animate({
                       marginLeft: "+="imageWidth;
                   },500);
               } 
                else {
                    console.log("This is the first image, can't slide left more.");
                }
            });

        });
```

**Also visual overwiew on subject:**
[image]

**Also JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/akpwb5b9/

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @vel sure I'll in a moment

Comment: @vel https://jsfiddle.net/akpwb5b9/

Comment: let me check...

Comment: do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/dysr4efd/2/?

Comment: @vel Oh, yeah! I can see i didn't use "+" to concate "+=" with variable, right...? :D Post is as answer and i'll mark it as best answer! :)

Comment: Glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var imageWidthToSlice = $(".gallery-element-wrapper").css("width");
        imageWidth = imageWidthToSlice.slice(0, -2);
        defaultMargin = $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").css("margin-left").slice(0, -2);
        numberOfElements = $(".gallery-element-wrapper").length;
        totalWidth = imageWidth * numberOfElements;

        $(document).on("click",".gallery-arrow-wrapper",function() {

           if ( $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").css("margin-left").slice(0, -2) != defaultMargin ) {
               $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").animate({
                   marginLeft: "+="+imageWidth
               },500);
           } 
            else {
          $(".gallery-element-wrapper:first").animate({
                   marginLeft: "+="+500
               },500);

                console.log("This is the first image, can't slide left more.");
            }
        });

    });
```